# W10 File History Folder Settings not sticking

Tags: windows, backup

This is quite frankly making me very mad.

I've turned on File History, and I've recently upgraded to Windows 10.

In the Backup Options (I presume the new name for File History), there are several folders I wish to not be backed up, named Dropbox, Google Drive, Downloads, and Desktop. I have gone into the settings and deselected these folders several times, but after some unknown amount of time (shorter than a couple of hours), the folders will be selected again for syncing. I remove them again, and some time later they add themselves back.

Having Google Drive, Downloads, and Desktop backed up is unnecessary and only a small nuisance, but Dropbox getting backed up is KILLING my storage space. It's my work dropbox account which has 150 GB in over 400,000 files (and that's just the stuff I selected). I synced it to my personal computer for the purpose of reducing that obscene file account and size by zipping up large folders (many of the files are duplicates and only needed for archival purposes, not immediate access) because my personal computer's SSD will fare much better for the task than my work computer's spinning rust drive (not to mention my work computer somehow has the absolute worst case of fragmentation I have ever seen).

The main problem is that Backup seems very...paranoid (generous?) about taking backups. I have it set to once per hour, and it looks like it takes a new version of every file very frequently, even if nothing changed. My 4 TB external drive that had nearly 1 TB free was eaten up within days. Clearing out all but the most recent version of file, it listed **4.5 million** files for deletion. I started this morning and I still have 3.2 million left.

It'll probably take another week or more to finish cleaning up the dropbox, so I need excluding it from the backup to stick. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been stuggling with this same bug a long time and finally found something that seems to work somehow.

[See this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/file-history-refuses-to-exclude-a-library-i/39bab658-9825-42ac-94c9-1cf9b176a401?page=3) and the post by DAdananski on  March 13, 2016. There is more valuable info there also.

Copy paste of the most important part:

> You cannot (AFAIK) avoid including libraries in the first place -
>   going through the dodgy Win-10-touch-style UI looks like it removes
>   them, but adds them back the next time it runs. Excluding doesn't seem
>   to work but after much fiddling it does: I got it working by excluding
>   both the path (e.g. D:\My Music\) and the library (Music), otherwise
>   it will still copy everything in that library over.